# Good code review tool for JSF , Java, and hibernate framework

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, findbugs

can anyone suggest good code review tool for JSF, Java, and Hibernate framework.
i need a good tool that can find potential bug in coding. for example, possible exception. connection handling code issue. i currently use FindBugs, but want to know if there is better tool than it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe sonar will help you: http://www.sonarsource.org/